# Print disk space with df, with headers, but only one particular row

Tags: linux, partition, disk-usage, disk

I have the following `df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
run             7,8G  1,8M  7,8G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   93G   40G   49G  45% /
tmpfs           7,8G  157M  7,7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7,8G   48M  7,8G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p4  204G  173G   31G  86% /run/media/test/drive
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   33M   64M  35% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   68K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I want to print only the root partition (/dev/nvme0n1p5) with headers - i.e. Size, Used Space, Available Space, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ask `df` to only show the free space on a given device:

```
$ df -h /dev/nvme0n1p5
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5   93G   40G   49G  45% /
```